# Timer isn't displaying count down in text label, why?

Tags: actionscript-3

**Code for timer:**

```
var oneSecTimer:Timer = new Timer (1000,60);
oneSecTimer.start();

oneSecTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER , timerListener );

oneSecTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE , onTimerComplete );
function timerListener (event:TimerEvent):void {
    secs.text.text = oneSecTimer;

}

function onTimerComplete (event:TimerEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(5);
    days=days+1;
}
```

When I run the movieclip I get, where the timer is supposed to be showing the countdown, a "[object timer]" message instead. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function timerListener (event:TimerEvent):void {
    secs.text.text = oneSecTimer.currentCount;

}
```

Rob

Comment: Thanks again, Rob ;). You're very intelligent!

Comment: Hi Noah, Thanks! :D If it is working, could you please accept my answer? I would much appreciate it. Cheers. Rob

Comment: I did, and I'll go back and do the same for the rest.

Comment: It should be something in your settings but I don't know Flash Builder that much, sorry.